# Signal R Integration Test Fails

Tags: c#, .net, azure, signalr

I have a Signal R Service set up from ASP .NET Core as below -

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR(options =>
{
    options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
}).AddAzureSignalR();
builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
});
app.UseCors();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapHub<MyHub>("/Chat");
```

I am trying to test it using WebApplicationFactory

```
var client = _factory.CreateClient();

 var connection = await StartConnectionAsync(_factory.Server.CreateHandler(), "Chat");

private static async Task<HubConnection> StartConnectionAsync(HttpMessageHandler handler, string hubName)
{
    var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl(new Uri($"http://localhost:5124/{hubName}"), o =>
        {
            o.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = _ => handler;
            o.Credentials = null;
        })
        .Build();

    try
    {
        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());   
    }

    return hubConnection;
}
```

I get the following exception when I try to establish a connection. Any ideas why?

```
'this.Transport' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
"Cannot access the Transport pipe before the connection has started."
```

Comment: This happens only with the SignalR .Net Client. I noticed that the signalR client in JS is different from the .net client. JS uses Web Sockets to connect, vs .net which uses HTTP protocol.

Comment: Microsoft really needs to add better samples.